# How to make format mask in DataGridView cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcell

**I need to make a format/mask in a cell that prevents the user from entering data that isn't relevant.**

The column cell contains date values like `"MM/YYYY"` without a day value.

I tried the following to make this definition but without success:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##/####" // || dd/yyyy
```

Also, I tried to go to the properties of `DataGridView` and define `Format` from there.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The method you're using for formatting [is a valid approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726576/3773066). There are a few issues that may be happening here. Please ensure:

1. The underlying data is of type `DateTime` and **not** type `string`. Type `string` will not apply the format as expected. (*See columns 1 and 2 in example below.*)
2. The individual `DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Style.Format` isn't being set to something different than your desired format. This would override the column formatting. (*See column 3 in example below.*)

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = date;
this.dataGridView1[1, 0].Value = date.ToString();
this.dataGridView1[2, 0].Value = date.ToString("MM/yyyy");
this.dataGridView1[3, 0].Value = date;

this.dataGridView1[3, 0].Style.Format = "MM/yyyy";

this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/yyyy";
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/yyyy";
this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/yyyy";
this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/yyyy";
```

[image: Cols output: 16/2016, 12/16/2016 8:52:17 AM, 12/2016, 12/2016]

As you can see from the output:

1. `Columns[0]` contains a `DateTime` and correctly formats as `"dd/yyyy"`.
2. `Columns[1]` contains a `string` and cannot be reformatted to `"dd/yyyy"`.
3. `Columns[2]` contains a formatted `string` and cannot be reformatted to `"dd/yyyy"`.
4. `Columns[3]` contains a `DateTime` and formatting is overridden by the cell format `"MM/yyyy"`.

---

To correct these issues, just set your cell value using the `DateTime` object and not any `string` representation.

In the case where you are getting this data from some outside source and it's *already* of type `string`, you can `Parse` it, but note that the missing portions of the `DateTime` object will be defaulted and there's really nothing you can do about that without having the original full data:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("10/2016");
Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", date.ToString());

// Output: 10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

---

**Validation**

If validating user input (and losing formatting on edits) is your main concern, consider the following method for validation to cancel an invalid edit:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime parsed;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out parsed))
    {
        this.dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Coupled with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644825/3773066) for reapplying your format using the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event handler. (Note that this also negates the need to ensure your data types are not `string`, but is more costly due to the event being triggered often.)