# Force date format in datagridview

Tags: c#

Good morning:
I have a Dgv with a cell that contains the Date.
In the Load of the Form I do the following:

dgvContratoRenov.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";

When executing the Project, the Date appears correctly (Ex: 05/04/2017).
My problem is when I am editing it does not respect the "/" and I must write the complete date. The idea is that it works as if it were a MaskedTextbox, that is, after entering the day skip to the position of the month and then the year.
It's possible? Thank you

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644788/c-sharp-datagridview-date-time-formatting-of-a-column/10644825#10644825) answer

Comment: It is fine but when I write the new date the "/" will continue to disappear, that is, I have to write the complete date, including the "/" ...